# Objective-c Warning for the webview of a dropbox plugin

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, webview, dropbox-api

Warning recieved : WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:initiatedByFrame: delegate:  The view passed in does not have a window.

dropbox plugin method for getting the files from dropbox inside it i have created an array to get the files and send it to javascript to display the output

getfiles:-

```
jscallback=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"getFilename(%@)",dropBoxArray]; 
       [self writeJavascript:jscallback];
```

Method defined in javascript

```
 window.getFilename=function(str)
{

  alert(str);

 cordova.exec(linkDropboxCB, linkDropboxFail,"DropboxPlugin","getfiles",  [""]);

 }
```

getfiles is the method in the dropbox plugin,which contains the above code.

Please help me to remove the warning.

Comment: As an aside, is there a reason you're not just using [dropbox.js](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js)?

Comment: Which dropbox.js are you talking about? The one which is created when we create a cordova project?If so,then it is present in my xcode and i dont use it for anything in my code.When i create the plugin with plugin.xml file it automatically add some lines of code into it.Thats all i have done in dropbox.js.

Comment: I meant the one I linked to. (The Dropbox JavaScript SDK.)

Comment: oh! i didn't have any idea about that!!!!!! I have linked Dropbox SDK Framework but not the one you mentioned Dropbox Javascript SDK.Is that a necessary thing?

Comment: It's not necessary. I just thought it would be easier than using the iOS SDK and then exposing it to JavaScript. (Why not just use the native JavaScript library?)

Comment: Since i am working with ios cordova i have to use the iOS SDK to implement the objective c functions.I will try by implementing the javascript one whether it works! .Since i have no idea about the cordova working,i am little confused with these...@smarx